# Call function from another function

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a calendar in Javascript, and I want to know how to get the calendar to call itself depending on which link the user clicks. At the moment the function has the name foo()

At the bottom, there are three different div links which are displayed depending on given circumstances. The (working) calendar was written in PHP, so I'm trying to port it into Javascript. Doing pretty well with that, but there's a few bugs that need ironing out. The problem is I just have to mimic the behavior of the PHP calendar, which sent POST values to the next or previous buttons to use as information for which month to display (etc).

I have tried this in two different ways with the Javascript calendar, first using a javascript void (onclick) link which called the calendar function, but apparently you can't pass variables to a function with onclick. The other way was using dom objects, but I faced a new dilemma: you can't call a function within itself.

So, how would I go about calling a function, by making another function and then calling the calendar from inside that one?
Thanks.

SystemError

An example:

```
    function cal()
    {

    document.write("<td align='left' colspan=7><div id='calendar'></div></td>");
    (function()
    {
            var lastday = cal[month];
                DOMcalendar = document.getElementById("calendar"),
                div = document.createElement("div");

            div.innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:void(0)'>Next</a>";
            div.onclick = function()
            {
                cal(lastday);
            }
            DOMcalendar.appendChild(div);
    })()

    }

    cal();
```

Comment: Please post the relevant part of you code. Also, *"how to get the calendar to call itself depending on which link the user clicks"* does not really explain what you are trying to do. What is the calendar? Can it even call itself? What does calling itself mean?

Comment: Any reason why you a) did not use any lib such as jquery and b) did not use one of the freely available calendar widgets?

Comment: A) Wanted to learn (knowing about date/time objects will come in handy), and B) If I wanted to customize it further I wouldn't have to try to understand someone else's code (so it's a little easier to add CSS, date ranges etc since I already know how it works). Oh and C) jQuery uses bandwidth (not a lot), but the less the user has to download the better.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand.

1. > you can't call a function within itself

O_O yes you can.

1. > you can't pass variables to a function with onclick

O_O yes you can. Just define a small lambda-function which will call the function you want with whatever parameters you wish, along the lines of

```
onclick="function(){myFuncWithArgs(arg1, arg2, arg3)}"
```

Or, better yet, just assign the callback in your javascript code. With jQuery it will look like

```
$("#yourButtonId").click(function(){
      // ...do whatever you like, variable called "this" 
      // is the DOM object of a button...
})
```

Comment: Your first code block is wrong for two reasons: The code is eval'd so you have a function statement which needs a name. Add `()` around it to turn it into a function expression. This still won't put the args in a closure though so they need to be global which is bad. All in all, the jQuery-based solution is the way to go.

Comment: @ThiefMaster that's what "along the lines of" means.